# VueJS: Component communication, the right way?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components

I would like to ask experts about the right “VueJS” way to implement SVG schema based on data (data-driven).

I have two totally different proof-of-concepts. The first one uses array’s methods and the second one uses bus.$on / bus.$emit method

So, I would like to hear from you what case is the right -or- is there better solution than my?

1st: http://play.ionic.io/app/197c7a5e2782
2nd: http://play.ionic.io/app/aeda99d21df7

If you need to play with it, please first fork the playground in the upper right corner - link “fork”.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see any Vue.js javascript? I only see: `angular.module('app', ['ionic']);`.

Comment: I already edited post with the right links, have no idea what happens...

Comment: You should generally avoid buses when possible. Your first option is better.

Comment: I would definitely go with option 1.

Comment: OK, many thanks to all.